# In vi/vim is there any way to make Visual Block Mode unconstrained by line endings?

Tags: vim, vi

In vi/vim is there any way to make Visual Block Mode unconstrained by line endings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:set virtualedit=block
```

See `:help 've'` for more details.

Comment: Note that for appending you still have to use `A` instead of `I` if the visual block extends past a line ending.